# PDFDocument File save

Tags: java, android, file, pdf, filewriter

Sorry, If this question is already asked,
I searched quite lot on this question but not got the solution.

I am developing an android app which generate PDF files using [PDFDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) Library of android.

There is some weird problem, After generating PDF File, it is visible in Phone's File Explorer but not visible in Computers File Explorer (Such as Android File Transfer of Mac,My Computer of Windows and File Explorer of Ubuntu), I think I am missing something in the code. Please Help.

**Here is my code**

```
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageinfo = new  PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(PAGEWIDTH,PAGEHEIGHT,1).create();


    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageinfo);

    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

    Paint paint = new Paint();


    paint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorName));
    canvas.drawText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),PAGEWIDTH/2,50,paint);


    document.finishPage(page);


    String targetPdf = "/sdcard/documents/myfile.pdf";
    File filepath = new File(targetPdf);
    try {

    filepath.createNewFile();

    document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filepath));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    getResources().getString(R.string.success),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
    catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    getResources().getString(R.string.error) + e.toString(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    document.close();
```

**Phone File Explorer Image**

[image]

**Computer File Explorer Image**

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by computer file explorer ? Emulator via Android Device monitor ?

Comment: I mean Android File Transfer on Mac and File Explorer on Ubuntu (When I connect phone to computer that file is not visible on computer)

Comment: No it won't be like that, may be your having some problem with transferring the data to Mac. If your file is created and able to open in the mobile that means your code work is done and it works fine., try to copy/transfer the file correctly

Comment: As you can see in the above image, file named 'myfile.pdf' is visible under document folder on phone, but when I open the 'Android File Transfer'  on Mac, except that file every other files are visible.

Comment: I think it is not properly saving the file

Comment: are u able to open the file in mobile ? If yes , i m pretty sure it is not the problem at all with saving. confirm it

Comment: Yes it can open in mobile. But when I connect mobile to computer for printing that file it is not visible on Computer

Answer (score 0):

If your file is created and able to open in the mobile that means your code work is done and it works fine. Since your able to save and open the file from the mobile phone , now the problem is not with the code but with transferring the data to mac ( as you mentioned).

In some of the cases `Android File Transfer` not list the all the files as mentioned [here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/cant-see-all-files-in-android-file-transfer-mac.468931/) and [here](https://www.patchworkoftips.com/android-file-transfer/6265/)

Try the below steps and check it again

- go to "Settings"
- select "Apps"
- show all Apps (menu "Show System")
- select the system app "Media Storage"
- select "Storage"
- Clear Cache and Clear Storage
- reboot phone and wait a while for Media Storage to index all your files again

Comment: Why cant you use a USB transfer to share the file to your computer

Comment: Actually I going to deploy this app on google play, that's why I don't wanted to limit the user